# Aggregate rows sum and repeat the new value

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, aggregate

I'm kinda new to R and I have a probably easy-to-solve question:

Here's my df:

```
site = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
N = c(5, 4, 2, 5, 10, 15, 6, 4, 29, 14, 10, 12)
df = data.frame(site, N)
```

What I want to do is aggregate the sum of N by site and add the new aggregated value to a new column (`df$N_total_site`, such as that, for example, rows that have `a` will have the value 11 (the aggregated value of sites **a**) in `df$N_total_site`

So, my new column, `df$N_total_site` has the same numbers of row as df and the aggregated value repeats throughout the rows used to aggregate it

What I want:

```
site = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
N = c(5, 4, 2, 5, 10, 15, 6, 4, 29, 14, 10, 12)
N_total_site = c(11, 11, 11, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 65, 65, 65, 65)
df = data.frame(site, N)
```

Thanks guys

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(site) %>% mutate(N_total_site = sum(N))`. Or in base, `df$N_total_site = with(df, ave(N, site, FUN = sum))`.

Comment: or:  `data.table::setDT(df)[, N_total_site := sum(N), by = site]`

Comment: Thanks guys, it solved!